# Install Google Chrome to AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, installation

I recently have installed a second drive to my PC and decided to install Windows 8 on it. While installing all of my favorite programs I noticed that my Google Chrome installed to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\

Is there a way of installing Google Chrome to

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application

No, I have not installed Google Pack and I also tried Alternate (offline) Google Chrome installer (Windows) but that did not work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default install location was changed last year, and IMO *about time* too. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-discuss/MrfbaVTH4NM) for example:

> Actually we did change the download page to install system-level by
>   default (and fall back to user level if that fails or the user says
>   "no" to the UAC prompt). Installing in AppData was never a security
>   measure, it was for convenience to make sure people could install
>   Chrome even without admin rights.
>
> Our data shows that *preferring* a system level (Program Files)
>   install with a fallback to user level improves the install success
>   rate.
>
> - [Mark Larson (Google)](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-discuss/MrfbaVTH4NM/0v_QhBdDmPQJ)

I don't understand why you'd prefer to install in AppData, but the quote seems to hint that saying No to the UAC prompt will naturally deny the installer access to Program Files, and so it'll install in AppData as before.

Comment: OK, great, but it is a bit inconsistent since I have installed Chrome in Win 8 few months back and it did not install to Program Files folder but the AppData one. I have also installed Chrome on other machines and it would usually install to AppData.

Comment: Did you install the same version of Chrome on every PC? Did you say yes to the UAC prompt every time? Was Chrome ever previously installed on those PCs?

Comment: Can't remember now. It's all good. I was having problem with --user-data-dir switch because of the fact that it installed in Program Files folder but I finally figured it out. Thanks

Comment: @Karan, What's the best way to install Chrome in a portable folder? Is it enough to just install it normally and then copy the folder into a USB?

Comment: @Pacerier: No idea, sorry (for the late response too). Try it and if it works you can write up your own question and answer it too.

Comment: @Pacerier Try using [Google Chrome Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable)