# Install software with a limited account on Windows XP Home Edition

Tags: windows-xp, limited-user-account

I am using a limited account for everyday use of Windows XP Home Edition. I have noticed that I could install Google Chrome with this account. How can this be possible? Is there a way to prevent installing application with this account?

Comment: I think that might be because chrome has a signed certificate so they don't need admin approval

Comment: @Griffin - Its actualy because of the way Chrome is installed.

Comment: that works also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome is relatively unique in that it installs itself under the user's profile directory, rather than a system-wide directory like `C:\Program Files` or similar. There's not any really easy way to prevent this type of software installation. There's lots of software out there that doesn't even need to be "installed" to run -- see [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/), for example.

If you really want to lock down software installation, there is software out there used to implement Windows-based kiosk systems. I'd suggest searching the web for "windows kiosk software".

Comment: This answer is outdated. Chrome [does install](http://superuser.com/a/545360/138343) in Program Files now by default, and only reverts to AppData if it is denied access to the former.